# Determine Row Number based on Nonzero Elements

Tags: r, dataframe

I am currently working with about 301 rows of data and want to determine the earliest point at which only a few particular columns are nonzero. However, I also want to ensure that this does not change. For example, the two columns are nonzero, while all other columns are zero, then later in the dataframe other columns are nonzero as well, this would mean that I would have to determine a later point which is "correct".

I have the data:

```
     1         x        y  z  xx  xy          xz
292  0 -8.965140 9.596890  0   0   0 -0.03147483
293  0 -9.079889 9.645991  0   0   0 -0.02722520
294  0 -8.967767 9.597826  0   0   0           0
295  0 -9.090561 9.650230  0   0   0 -0.02685287
296  0 -9.081568 9.646105  0   0   0 -0.02716237
297  0  0.000000 0.000000  0   0   0  0.00000000
298  0  0.000000 0.000000  0   0   0  0.00000000
299  0 -9.098568 9.628576  0   0   0 -0.02654466
300  0 -9.089815 9.646099  0   0   0 -0.02681748
301  0 -8.998078 9.605140  0   0   0           0
```

As you can see, only the variables `x` and `y` are selected for row `294`, however, the `xz` variable contains values after that until the `301` row. Is it possible to develop a function which tells me at which point is the minimum row where I see only `x` and `y` as nonzero and it remains that way until the final row of the dataframe?

I'm sorry if it's difficult to understand the question, I found it difficult asking how exactly to accomplish this issue.

EDIT: I presume I could use something like

```
  which((df$x != 0 & df$y != 0 &
           (df[, 1] | df[, 4] == 0))
```

but then I need to somehow expand the second or statement to all columns of `df`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. In your example, what is the expected output, and why?

Comment: In the example, the expected output would be `301` because it is the last row in the data in which only `x` and `y` are nonzero, and all other values are zero. Essentially, I want to determine the rows where *only* `x` and `y` are nonzero, I think I can solve the rest of the problem from there.

Comment: I think then `which(df$x != 0 & df$y != 0 & rowSums(df[, !names(df) %in% c("x", "y")] != 0) == 0)` is what you want. You can put `max()` around it to get only the last row for which this is true.

Comment: I had a small mistake, which I edited

Comment: Actually, the code you provided before the edit seemed to work. Now I need to figure out if the resulting vector includes `301` or not. Thanks

Comment: The code before the edit checks whether the sum of all columns is 0, but that could technically be the case if one column is `1` and another is `-1`. The code after the edit checks if all columns are exactly zero. Happy to have helped!